# Nvidia FX 5500 UNCLAIMED in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, display, nouveau

I have a pretty old system (HP t617m with pentium 4 2.6 ghz) that Im trying to revive using Xubuntu 18.04 32-bit. In order to do so, I bought recently a Nvidia FX 5500 PCI (I have no AGP ports), which I never be able to make it work. I know that are a free driver called nouveau, and I want to use it. In order to use a PCI video card, I set in BIOS the change between onboard and pci graphics. When I make the change, the card gives the HP boot screen normal, but after that it just becomes a black screen. Then Im force to set again the onboard graphics, and everything is normal.

The `lshw -C display` shows:

```
    *-display                 
       description: Display controller
       product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:ef000000-ef07ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NV34 [GeForce FX 5500]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: b
       bus info: pci@0000:01:0b.0
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5
       resources: memory:ed000000-edffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ec080000-ec09ffff
```

`lspci | grep VGA` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 03)
01:0b.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5500] (rev a1)
```

`lsmod | grep nouveau` and `ubuntu-drivers devices` shows nothing

What I have tried:

-Fresh install, even using different distros -> Always appears UNCLAIMED in lspci
-Install nouveau using apt-get install firmware-nouveau -> same problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: You weren't specific as to what 18.04 ISO you tried to install.  I used a `hp dx6120mt (pentium 4, 3gb, winfast clone of nvidia 7600gt)` in QA-testing (up to Xubuntu 19.04 actually; but for 18.04.5 last was http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/415/builds/218703/testcases/1300/results) but I do recall issues with some cards/boxes and the 5.4/HWE kernel (but were fine with older 5.3/HWE, but I'd opt for a 4.15/GA kernel fully-updated by choice for those x86/i386 boxes).  Which 18.04 ISO did you try?

Comment: Do you talk about which kernel Im running? uname -r says 5.4.0-65, so I believe I tried to use the 5.4 iso. Where do I find the 4.15?

Comment: 5.4 is the HWE or hardware enablement stack kernel (ie. the 20.04 kernel). The original 18.04 (GA) kernel was 4.15, 18.04.2 came with 18.10's 4.18 kernel, 18.04.3 used 19.04's 5.0 kernel, 18.04.4 used 19.10's 5.3 kernel, 18.04.5 media used the final HWE 5.4 kernel... The installation media (ISO used) controls what is installed but once installed they'll update and you end up with GA (installs with 18.04 or 18.04.1 media) or HWE (18.04.2 or later)... https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  refer first link

Comment: How can I download the Xubuntu 18.04 with 4.15 kernel? or I need to downgrade the kernel in order to use the card?

Comment: I don't know your card, so I don't know what's best for you. I provided clues only with what I found testing using a 7600gt on a pentium 4 box. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ allows download of older releases (ubuntu, anyway). Xubuntu 18.04 & 18.04.1 ISOs default to GA kernel (where 18.04.2 & later default to HWE). You can switch from HWE to GA post-install, but I recall having difficulty doing it using a 18.04.5 test system I had issues with, so starting with 18.04.4 (5.3 kernel) which didn't have issue was easier, or starting from 18.04 or 18.04.1 media and no change was needed.

Comment: FYI:  I asked on IRC where you can download old ISOs, and was provided with http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04.1/release/ from Ubuntu member "Maik/darkera"

Comment: I tried to use the old kernel images, without success, do you know other options?

Comment: Install (or boot) with `nomodeset` option. Your card is listed as supported (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsNvidia) but you may need to add support (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto) and I see success stories using the 4.15 kernel, but I've not used the device sorry.

Comment: I made a fresh install, using the 18.04.1 iso, and 'uname -r' still shows 5.4.0-65. However, when I enter in /lib/modules/, it only appears 4.15. Somehow, I have the 5.4 kernel with no modules but it is shown, and the 4.15 have every module I use, even nouveau. When I try to 'modprobe nouveau' shows an error saying this module is not charged in the 5.4 kernel. So, its a kernel problem.

Comment: The 5.4 kernel has me baffled, as 18.04.1 is from 2018-July (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/26/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-released/) which is more than a year before the 5.4 kernel even existed (released 24-Nov-2019 upstream)  so it can't be on the media unless you didn't have 18.04.1 media; did you verify it?  Even if you don't install, you can test using the *live* system, but 5.4 kernel on 18.04.1 media baffles me. If however you caused HWE to be added as well, you should be able to select the 4.15 GA kernel at grub (and make it default).